# Why my mysql doesn't updating?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I tried to update my database via php, but the database not updating.

this is my HTML Code:

```
<form method=post>
    <input type="radio" name="osis" value= 1 >Nadiya<br>
    <input type="radio" name="osis" value= 2 >Hafizh<br>
    <input type="radio" name="osis" value= 3 >Aina<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
<?php
if(isset($POST['osis'])){
    $value = $_POST['osis'];

if($value == 1){
    mysql_query('UPDATE kandidat_osis SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE id = 1');
}
else if($value == 2){
    mysql_query('UPDATE kandidat_osis SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE id = 2');
}
else if($value == 3){
    mysql_query('UPDATE kandidat_osis SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE id = 3');
}
mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
</form>
```

but I simply cannot solve it, I search around the internet and search engine but the database still not updating

Comment: have you tried to run your query directly to mysql if it did an udpate?

Comment: have you a mysql connection?? on the other note use mysqli or pdo ..mysql open to sql injetion

Comment: Notice that you have a typo in `if(isset($POST['osis']))` it's `$_POST`

Comment: don't know if its relavant but you have to close your </form>. and you should give your submit input a name and use isset on that button to check for a submission?

Comment: @XicoXperto write that as answer (:

Comment: @RohitKumar I don't see how this code is open for sql injection since the value is tested with specific values

Comment: **PLEASE** stop using **mysql_*** functions as they are deprecated and will be removed from PHP 7, start using **mysqli_*** or **PDO**

Comment: @XicoXperto , are these snippet are all codes for a project ..as @@Naruto is also have a point .. mysql functions are never are secure way untill you do a vast validation & verification

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have a typo in `if(isset($POST['osis']))` it's `$_POST`

Answer (score -2):

Use name as Array or give different names

```
<?php if(isset($POST['osis'])){
                    $value = $_POST['osis'];

                    if($value == 1){
                        mysql_query('UPDATE kandidat_osis SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE id = 1');
                    }
                    else if($value == 2){
                        mysql_query('UPDATE kandidat_osis SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE id = 2');
                    }
                    else if($value == 3){
                        mysql_query('UPDATE kandidat_osis SET vote = vote + 1 WHERE id = 3');
                    }
                    mysql_close($conn);}
                ?>

<form method=post>
                <input type="radio" name="osis[]" value= 1 >Nadiya<br>
                <input type="radio" name="osis[]" value= 2 >Hafizh<br>
                <input type="radio" name="osis[]" value= 3 >Aina<br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: and check your MySQL connection connected or not

Comment: can you explain , what comes new because of your changes??